# Execute "select_for_update" with Django ORM in loop.run_in_executor

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-asyncio, django-orm

#### Env:

python - 3.6.4
django - 2.1.7
DB - mysql

#### Sample:

```
from django.db import transaction

async def some_method():
    with transaction.atomic():
        obj = await loop.run_in_executor(
            None,
            lambda: models.ModelName.objects.select_for_update().get(id=obj_id)
        )
        # do other stuff
```

Following error is thrown:

```
     raise TransactionManagementError('select_for_update cannot be used outside of a transaction.')
 django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: select_for_update cannot be used outside of a transaction.
```

Similar code could be ran without error:

```
async def some_method():
    with transaction.atomic():
        obj = models.ModelName.objects.select_for_update().get(id=obj_id)
        # do other stuff
```

And any other query without `select_for_update()` could be done in `loop.run_in_executor` e.g. `obj.save()`

#### Context:

As an experiment I try to "migrate" Django application to `aiohttp` with keeping Django ORM. (please do not ask "why" - it's as experiment)

#### Questions:

1. Is it possible to call select_for_update() in `run_in_executor` or
   in other method?
2. if I call `obj.save()` and `obj2.save()` in `loop.run_in_executor` is it indeed ran in same transaction

like:

```
 async def some_method():
    with transaction.atomic():
        await loop.run_in_executor(
            None,
            obj.save
        )
        await loop.run_in_executor(
            None,
            obj2.save
        )
```

**Purpose**: let's assume that call to DB takes 2 seconds (just assume, reason could be: connection or non-optimized DB, whatever) - I need to call DB without blocking.(I know that there are several "async" ORM libraries for Mysql, but I try to keep Django ORM)

Comment: Maybe the current transaction is stored thread-locally? Try moving the `with` statement and the `select_for_update` to a function (ordinary one, not async def) and see if that helps.

Comment: @user4815162342 That is an idea to keep in in `async def` method.